# PHP INI changes have no effect

Tags: php, apache

Today i create a new vagrant box with Ubuntu 14.04 and PHP 5.4.33. I would like to change the "date.timezone, upload_max_filesize".

The php.ini is defined in

"/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini"

and some addionals configs is defined under the folder

"/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d".

I make my changes and restart the apache server, but my changes do not effect. Have anyone an idea why my changes not effect?

Comment: Apache *and* FPM master process restarted?

Comment: This was the first time i work with FPM. Now i restart it sudo /etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart and this solve my problem. From now on i must restart apache and fpm on php ini changes every time, correct?

Comment: Apache doesn't even care. FPM is the PHP process.

Comment: Ok mario many thank's, you saved my day :)